# SSL or Proxy Errors using Python Requests Module

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

If I set verify to False, I get proxy errors.

```
    api_url = constants.ERV_API_URL_ME
    credentials = {"username": constants.ERV_API_USERNAME, "password": constants.ERV_API_PASSWORD}

    headers = {}
    headers["Content-Type"]= "application/json"
    headers["Accept"] =  "application/json"
    headers["Authorization"] = "LONG_SESSION_ID_HERE"
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    response.json()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\python_rpa\main.py",
> line 81, in 
> response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, verify=False)   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\rpa\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 75, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\rpa\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\rpa\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 542, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\rpa\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 655, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\rpa\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 510, in send
> raise ProxyError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mycompany.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /api/v21.1/objects/users/me (Caused by
> ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such
> file or directory')))

If I add proxies, I get SSL errors:

```
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, verify=False, proxies=constants.proxyDict)
```

If I set Verify = True, I get SSL Errors.

```
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, verify=True)
```

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mycompany.com',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v21.1/objects/users/me
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of
> protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))

I even tried creating a self signed client certificate and private key and using this, but I get SSL errors.

```
 response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers,  cert=('certificate.crt', 'privatekey.key'), verify=True, proxies=constants.proxyDict)
```

So much for the friendly http request library for humans....PostMan works fine, that has an autodetect proxy set in settings, and it fails when turned off.

My proxyDict is as follows:

```
https_proxy = "https://server.mycompany.net:9480"
http_proxy = "http://server.mycompany.net:9480"

proxyDict = {
            "https":    https_proxy,
            "http":     http_proxy
            }
```

Comment: The https_proxy should very likely be `http://...`, not `https://...`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks....plagued me for years.  Why is that?

Comment: See the duplicate answer for a deeper explanation.